# How can i return stdout to value on python?

Tags: python, paramiko

I made some script.
I want  return stdout to value on python.

But my script not work.

below is my script.

```
import paramiko
import sys

from paramiko import AutoAddPolicy

sip = raw_input('IP\n')
sid = raw_input('ID\n')
spass = raw_input('PW')

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=sip, username=sid, password=spass)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('hostname')
s_info = stdout
sys.stdout.close()

client.close()

print (s_info)
```

my script occurred below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 17, in
>   
>       print (s_info) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mentions, you're trying to write to a stream after you've already closed it. the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) redirects to stdout by default, and you've already closed that here `sys.stdout.close()`

In order for it to work, just comment or delete that line

Comment: How can call stdout value after close?